# XmlDataContractSerializer middleware fails for Dictionary<string, object>

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-middleware

It seems AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters middleware fails while serializing generated response for Dictionary<string,object>

here are my dictionary's keys and values

```
Key1          value1
someKey1     someValue
key2          value2
someKey2     ICollection<TSource>
```

Serialization of this dictionarty response fails for media-type *Accept: application/xml.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Serialization Failed for application/xml in Webapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45426622/serialization-failed-for-application-xml-in-webapi)

Comment: You can try this [converter](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30524#issuecomment-524619972).